# Sed regex returning incorrect results

Tags: regex, bash, sed

This is returning incorrect results:

```
sed -regex -no print '/everythingbetween/,/thesephrases/p'
```

**Cool.** Now let me step through my sed command:

```
'/<literal string...="[collectionofcharacters(I also tried ^ at the beginning)]
             .(anycharacter)+(greedy)?(lessgreedy, or until first instance of the following)
              DBAppender(string literal)/,/ \/>(another string literal)/p'
```

**My actual statement**

```
 sed -rn '/<appender-ref ref="[ET].+?DBAppender/,/\/>/p'
```

**Result.**

```
      <appender-ref ref="ErrorDBAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="TracingDBAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="ErrorDBAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="ErrorDBAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="ErrorDBAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="TracingDBAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="ErrorDBAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="TracingDBAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="ErrorDBAppender" />
```

Please, someone tell my why "Rolling" is showing up when I'm even SPECIFYING the character after the " MUST either be a E or a T, NOT AN R!?

Edit: Please, if you're going to tell me how to do this with another tool, specify why it isn't working with sed first.

Comment: The start line isn't checked for the end pattern.  The "Rolling" lines end the group.

Comment: I see. It might be better to simply do a 's/<app.+?etc/\/>/g', but in this insstance, why is it skipping the first />, and also adding '/^.+?<appender... does not help, same results. How do I declare that it should be the only thing on the line?

Comment: Problem is that you are matching till `/>` which matches till last instance of `/>`. You can use `sed -rn '/<appender-ref ref="[ET].+?DBAppender/p' file`

Comment: What's the purpose of `/,/\/>/` in your pattern? It's causing the `sed` command to return incorrect results.

Comment: the //,// finds all things between those two phrases. I was using it from another command, and forgot that I could do the same thing without the second phrase. Just got caught up is all. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You are matching all the lines in a line range, that begins with pattern:

```
<appender-ref ref="[ET].+?DBAppender
```

and ends with pattern:

```
/>
```

I think your intention was to match the `/>` on the same line, but once the first pattern is matched it moves on to the next line and will match any line including the `/>`.